# VGA can't detect Monitor and turn to sleep mode

Tags: display, graphics-card, gpu

I have my new PC for a 4 months, everything worked perfect till one morning I turned it on, and the monitor (SAMSUNG) tried to detect the graphic card (ASUS R9 290) without any success and turned to sleep mode. The monitor works without problems with another PC or Laptop. I connected the VGA card to my tv LG, and it works without problems, after when I connected it back to my monitor, it works, but not stable, in the screen resolution properties it doesn't recognize the monitor, it's going in safe mode for any entering to game, installing some program or restarting of the computer. I tried to put my GTX 650 into that slot (there are 2 slots for graphic cards, and I tried both of them) instead of R9 290, and everything works without problems. So I decided to connect my GTX 650 that works perfect to x16 slot, and the R9 290 to x8 slot... connecting the monitor to GTX650, it detect also the R9 290 without any problems, but when I disconnect the monitor from the GTX650 and connect to R9 290, the monitor going to safe mode again. I tried all these connections with many different cables (all the cables are in working condition).
If somebody can help me, I will be grateful :)
Thanks

Comment: Your monitor doesn't detect your graphics card... your graphics card reads what your monitor is capable of and then gives you available options (some can be overridden and thus cause your screen to "go out of range" and your screen goes to sleep). Have you tried to see if there are any Windows drivers for your monitor? This will help Windows and your graphics card work out what your monitor is capable of. You may also want to restart Windows in low resolution mode (F8) - this will force your graphics card into (I think) 800x600 and should allow you to choose a suitable resolution.

Comment: @BigChris did you mean low resolution mode or safe mode?

Comment: Low resolution mode. This is a full load of Windows but the graphics resolution is overridden. "Safe mode" is exactly that, a minimal set of services to run Windows - this will not resolve your problem :)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for reply! I use Win.7 Home. The driver of my monitor is installed, when I connect the graphic card to TV and then dissconnet it and connect to monitor, it detects the monitor as "unknown monitor", and in the menu of Device Manager it doesn't show me any monitors, so I can't update or install monitor driver while the R9 290 is connected.

Comment: I tried to re install windows and drivers several times, different resolutions, safe mode. nothing helps